# Looking for a clean and seamless discussion+documents board and/or Google groups alternative

Tags: wiki, collaboration, google-groups

I've been trying to find a clean, fresh and nice-looking alternative online tool for writing topic pages and then discussing them.

Ideally, this should be a wiki page (where users are able to embed images and use custom fonts and colors) with Google docs-style commenting and seamless sharing/commenting through Google+.

Does anyone know of anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much Google+ 3rd-party integration yet because Google hasn't made the API available to the public. They do have a invite-only developer test going on soon However yesterday I saw that Google actually just bought a small start-up called [Fridge](http://frid.ge/). That company had a lot of interesting features that are now likely to be integrated into Google+.

Features from Fridge's homepage:

- Create a group to share with friends & family
- Organize events, outings and parties
- Plan and coordinate group vacations
- Manage classmates and study groups
- Collaborate with co-workers and team mates

In the mean time, depending on the size of the group I guess, you could perhaps use Google Doc's collections to manage your topics, sharing and commenting.

Comment: Thanks, I've already heard of Fridge and it's group features. Yes G+ is buying them out, they tell about that at the site title. We'll see how far G+ goes, cause at the moment I can filter persons only - but not group or tag person has posted to - so this is useless for company discussions because of all other clutter.